# Design a Data Structure with insert (key,value),get,delete & get last accessed key operations with each O(1) complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I can create a class with members map to store key,value and stack
to maintain the history of operations performed onto the class
objects. However, the tricky part is last key retrieval in O(1)-
if a key has been deleted, I would require to search the entire
stack for valid key in the map, which will be of O(n) in the worst case.

For instance

```
insert(a,1)
insert(b,1)
get(a) -> output 1
get_last_key -> output a 
delete(a)
get_last_key -> output b
```

Is there a better way of designing the structure for better performance?

Comment: Define "performance". Everything is a trade-off. If you are worried about run time then you trade-off with space. But this is not quite on-topic for SO.

Comment: @jdv O(1) for all the operations

Comment: My point is that asking SO to design some unknown program for you is not on-topic.

Comment: space isn't the constraint.

Comment: So is primarily about coding problems, so your best bet is to write some code and find some hotspots with benchmarking if the performance isn't _measurably_ right. Imaginary algorithm design is not really within the purview of SO.

Comment: Note that for each key, you only care about most recent access. Keeping a history of more than that is wasteful. If you use a set of keys in history, you can reduce the O(n) to O(log keys). If you use a linked list + a map for key -> linked list pointer, you can make that into O(1)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using a traditional hash table to store the keys and values. Additionally, maintain a doubly-linked list of the keys, ordered from most-recently-accessed to least-recently-accessed. Finally, maintain a hash table associating each key with its linked list cell.

After doing any operation other than a delete on a key k, you can reword the linked list to have the node for k at the front in time O(1) as follows:

- Use the auxiliary hash table to look up the linked list cell for k.
- Splice that cell out of the linked list.
- Prepend that cell to the front of the linked list.

To delete a key, delete the key/value pair from the main hash table, then unlink and delete the linked list entry for that key from the linked list and remove that key from the secondary hash table.

All these operations run in (expected) time O(1).

(For what it’s worth, this strategy is commonly used to build caches. The idea of running a linked list through items that reorders based on recency lets you do all sorts of other things, like remove old items from a table that haven’t been used in a long time.)